# how to handle error in deepFace.analyze() when no face is found?

Tags: python, error-handling, face-detection, deepface

```
img=cv2.imread(face.jpg)
predictions= DeepFace.analyze(img)
```

`Error: Face could not be detected. Please confirm that the picture is a face photo or consider to set enforce_detection param to False.`

setting `enforce_detection` to `False` is causing it to read emotions even if there is no face in the image

how do we handle this error so that it tells us that there is no face?

Answer (score 5):

The best way of solving this problem is reading the error and it says: "consider to set enforce_detection param to False."

so you can simply solve this by not forcing
a face detection.

```
return DeepFace.verify(img1, img2 , enforce_detection=False)['verified']
```

I had the error with that code for your code it will probably be

```
DeepFace.analyze(img1 , enforce_detection=False)
```

Response on edit:

This is a different problem, you could first try to detect if there is a face on the foto using this approach:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-detect-and-extract-faces-from-an-image-with-opencv-and-python

and only analyze for emotions, knowing there is a face!

Answer (score -1):

Try this script here! Good luck!

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import os
file = open("path to file you want to save your results in", 'w')

# giving directory for your pictures
dirname = "the path of the directory"
  
for files in os.listdir(dirname):
    try:
        obj = DeepFace.analyze(img_path = ("the path of the directory" + files), actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
        file.write(files)
        file.write(str(obj) + "\n")
    except Exception: 
        file.write(files)
        file.write("face_was not detected" + "\n")
file.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `try: except:` block, it should work.

Comment: Please provide a detailed answer.

Comment: terrible answer, that simply catches and ignores all exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

```
try:
  img=cv2.imread(face.jpg)
  predictions= DeepFace.analyze(img)
except:
  print("No face detected")
```

Comment: this code is not running the deepFace.analyze(img) and giving the no face detected for all the images even if that image contains a face

Comment: The only thing that code does different than yours is catching the error. So apparently the ML model is not recognizing the face.

Comment: terrible answer, that simply catches and **ignores all exceptions**.